# How to make "changing mac adress" a script the best way?

Tags: scripts

I figured out how to change my mac address of my network card:

```
sudo ip addr                                    # Show details
sudo ifconfig eth0 down                         # deactivate network card
sudo ifconfig eth0 hw ether DESIRED_MAC_ADDRESS # change mac address
sudo ifconfig eth0 up                           # activate network card
sudo ip addr                                    # show details again
```

What would be the best way to make this a script which I could start each time I need this modification? Also where do I have to put this generated script? What is the standard folder for this?

I don't want it to be started every time Ubuntu starts. (But it would be nice to know how this is done, though. Where would be the best place to store it in that case?)

Appreciate any suggestions!

Comment: Not answering your question, but I'd take a look at program `macchanger`. Changing and resetting your MAC is as simple as `sudo macchanger -m 00:11:22:33:44:55 eth0` and `sudo macchanger -p eth0`.

Comment: Thanks for this hint, but I already tried `macchanger`. It doesn't work for me. That's why I figured out the alternative above.

Comment: I would but it in ~/bin and add that to path, but I'm a bit paranoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you mean by 'the best way'. The regular, easy and practical way would be to copy/paste the commands into a text file named, for example, best_way, save it anywhere you want, for example, the home folder, and, ... believe it or not, that's it.

To run it, `cd` to the folder with the file, then `sudo bash ./best_way`.

PS: Since you'll be using `sudo` to run the script, there is no need to precede each command with `sudo`.

Comment: This approach didn't work. I assume it takes some time for `ifconfig eth0 down` to be processed and to deactivate the network card. Is there a way to tell the script to wait until the process is done, then execute the next line?

Comment: Try the `sleep` command (in seconds, e.g. `sleep 1.23` for 1s and 230 ms).

Comment: @Aufwind: I don't think ifconfig command is asynchronous, i.e. it does not return control to the calling script until it finished what it was doing. So there's no need to do anything special to ensure the process is done. If you have any problems they're likely caused by something else

Comment: +1. I have a similar script that does what it is supposed to do without having to delay it with `sleep`.

Answer (score 2):

The debian way of setting MAC address is to specify `hwaddress` option in the `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

It's not well documented, but you can find a lot of useful information [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ifupdown/+bug/109725).